# php & CI file upload

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a file input element which generate by ajax/jquery.load(). and when I want to move the uploaded file, I got an error that says I have no file to upload.

I tried it with CI file uploading class and php move_uploaded_files(), but it return the same error..

Here's my code with CI

```
$config['upload_path'] = './'.$uploadpath.'/answer';
$config['allowed_types'] = '*';
$config['max_size'] = '2048';
$config['file_name'] = $probid.".ans";
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if(!$this->upload->do_upload("contanswer".$i))
{
//do some error handling
}
```

Here's my code with php move_uploaded_files

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["continput".$i]["tmp_name"], $uploadpath.'/input');
```

FYI, `$i` is an index variable, because I've some file input element on my page..

Am I missing something in my code??
thx

Comment: yes, is this inside a loop? is that why u have $i?

Comment: yes, that code is inside a loop an I use $i in that loop..

Comment: you have `contanswer` and `continput` - which are referring to two different `file input`; is this a typo?

Comment: And if you are using CI's form helper to generate the input, it's default name is `userfile`; something to bear in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to get the full $_FILES array and check if you are getting the values right:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

then see what values you get from the form, maybie there is some typo in the name? also check the $i variable value, maybie it starts from different value

Comment: this would be a good comment instead. How about you give more details to make it a good answer

Comment: nothing returned... When I tried `print_r($_FILES);` only, it return array().. but when I tried `print_r($_FILES["continput".$i]);` it returned nothing...

Comment: so if your tried `print_r($_FILES);` and it return empty array() that means you don't pass the data properly, maybie you don't set the form to `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ?